# Bipartite Graph Construction

Tags: graph-theory, set-partition, bipartite-graphs

> Assume $m$, $n$ to be positive integers. Given two partitions $[mn]=A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \dots \cup A_m$ and $[mn]=B_1 \cup B_2 \cup \dots \cup B_m$ of $[mn]$ into sets of cardinality $n$, show that the sets $A_i$ can be renumbered in a way s.t. $A_i \cap B_i \ne \emptyset$ for all $i \in [m]$.

I am trying to construct a connected/associated bipartite graph such that each set $A_i$ or $B_i$ is a vertex and the edge represent the intersection of two sets/vertices (and maybe utilize Hall's theorem.)

But I am having a bit of trouble to construct such a graph and am not sure if "$A_i \cap B_i \ne \emptyset$ for all $i \in [m]$" in the question means the same $i$ or the $i$'s can be different.

Comment: Yes, you're on the right track ! In the question, the $i$ must be the same, but you have renumbered them, so you made a permutation of the indexes on each side ; which means you indeed need to find a matching between the sets.

Comment: Your edges should represent whether two sets can be matched. Take care though, your title says "Connected" but you have no warranty that the graph you're constructing  will connected...